# Unmarshal hcl to struct using viper

Tags: go, configuration, viper-go

Trying to `Unmarshal` a `hcl` config file to a struct, using `viper`, this error is returned: `1 error(s) decoding:\n\n* 'NATS' expected a map, got 'slice'`. What is missing?

The code:

```
func lab() {
    var c conf

    // config file
    viper.SetConfigName("draft")
    viper.AddConfigPath(".")
    viper.SetConfigType("hcl")
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }

    log.Info(viper.Get("NATS")) // gives [map[port:10041 username:cl1 password:__Psw__4433__ http_port:10044]]

    if err := viper.Unmarshal(&c); err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }

    log.Infow("got conf", "conf", c)
}

type conf struct {
    NATS struct {
        HTTPPort int
        Port     int
        Username string
        Password string
    }
}
```

And the config file (`draft.hcl` inside current directory):

```
NATS {
    HTTPPort = 10044
    Port     = 10041
    Username = "cl1"
    Password = "__Psw__4433__"
}
```

**Edit**

Have checked this struct with `hcl` package and it gets marshaled/unmarshalled correctly. Also this works correctly with `yaml` and `viper`.

There is a difference between these two where `log.Info(viper.Get("NATS"))` is called. While the `hcl` version returns a slice of maps, the `yaml` version returns a map: `map[password:__psw__4433__ httpport:10044 port:10041 username:cl1]`.

Comment: @Kavesh can you share the yaml version which you are referring?

Comment: @Anuruddha This gist: https://gist.github.com/dc0d/7cb146f6650259d6f299223ff410ecc9

Answer (score 5):

Your conf struct is not matching the HCL. When converted to json the HCL looks like below

```
{
"NATS": [
    {
      "HTTPPort": 10044,
      "Password": "__Psw__4433__",
      "Port": 10041,
      "Username": "cl1"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the `Conf` Struct should look like this

```
type Conf struct {
    NATS []struct{
        HTTPPort int
        Port     int
        Username string
        Password string
    }
}
```

Modified code

```
package main
import (
  "log"
  "github.com/spf13/viper"
  "fmt"
)

type Conf struct {
    NATS []struct{
        HTTPPort int
        Port     int
        Username string
        Password string
    }
}

func main() {
    var c Conf
    // config file
    viper.SetConfigName("draft")
    viper.AddConfigPath(".")
    viper.SetConfigType("hcl")
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(viper.Get("NATS")) // gives [map[port:10041 username:cl1 password:__Psw__4433__ http_port:10044]]

    if err := viper.Unmarshal(&c); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(c.NATS[0].Username)
}
```

Comment: I've checked it and this works correctly with `hcl` package. Also it works correctly with `viper` and `yaml`.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please consider reviewing the edit too.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is more than two years old now, but I came across the same issue recently.

I'm using viper to be able to load different configuration files into a Go struct, allowing configuration in JSON, YAML, TOML, HCL, just pick your favourite :)

HCL file format does wrap a map into a slice because it allows redefining a section like:

```
section = {
  key1 = "value"
}

section = {
  key2 = "value"
}
```

which is something that is not supported by the other formats.

And here's how I fixed it:

- My solution implies each new block will override any previous definition of the same key, and keep all the others. You can do some merging magic but I didn't need to.

1. You need to make a hook to convert a slice of maps into a map:

```
// sliceOfMapsToMapHookFunc merges a slice of maps to a map
func sliceOfMapsToMapHookFunc() mapstructure.DecodeHookFunc {
    return func(from reflect.Type, to reflect.Type, data interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        if from.Kind() == reflect.Slice && from.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Map && (to.Kind() == reflect.Struct || to.Kind() == reflect.Map) {
            source, ok := data.([]map[string]interface{})
            if !ok {
                return data, nil
            }
            if len(source) == 0 {
                return data, nil
            }
            if len(source) == 1 {
                return source[0], nil
            }
            // flatten the slice into one map
            convert := make(map[string]interface{})
            for _, mapItem := range source {
                for key, value := range mapItem {
                    convert[key] = value
                }
            }
            return convert, nil
        }
        return data, nil
    }
}
```

2. then you need to create a DecodeHook:

```
configOption := viper.DecodeHook(mapstructure.ComposeDecodeHookFunc(
        sliceOfMapsToMapHookFunc(),
        mapstructure.StringToTimeDurationHookFunc(),
        mapstructure.StringToSliceHookFunc(","),
    ))
```

the two other hooks are the default ones so you might want to keep them

then you pass the option to the Unmarshal method

```
viper.Unmarshal(&c, configOption)
```

With this method you don't need a slice around your structs or your maps. Also that makes it compatible with the other configuration file formats